# Can there be an infinite $\kappa$ with $\kappa\to(\omega)^\omega_2$ in $\mathsf{ZF}$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is a standard result in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\kappa\not\rightarrow(\omega)^\omega_2$ for infinite $\kappa$, but the proof I've seen requires well ordering $[\kappa]^\omega$ so it doesn't work in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Can there be an infinite $\kappa$ for which $\kappa\to(\omega)^\omega_2$ holds if we drop the axiom of choice? I'm being vague in what infinite means here because I'm interested in results using any of the notions of infinite available in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: Isn't it a consequence of AD?

Comment: I know nothing about AD, but if you have a reference showing that it is I'll accept the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is consistent to have such cardinals. In fact, it is consistent relative to an inaccessible cardinal that $\omega\to(\omega)^\omega_2$. This is a famous result of Mathias, in

> [MR0491197 (58 #10462)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=491197). Mathias, A. R. D. *[Happy families](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(77)90006-7)*. Ann. Math. Logic **12** (1977), no. 1, 59–111.

(It is still open whether the inaccessible cardinal is required.)

The result holds in Solovay's model where all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable. It also holds under the assumption of $\mathsf{AD}^+$, in particular, in all known models of $\mathsf{AD}$.

$\mathsf{AD}^+$ is a technical strengthening of the axiom of determinacy $\mathsf{AD}$, and it is open whether both theories are actually the same. All our techniques to obtain models of determinacy give us models of $\mathsf{AD}^+$. It is open whether $\mathsf{AD}$ suffices.

Actually, $\mathsf{AD}$ gives us many additional examples of cardinals $\kappa$ with the required partition property, and much more. For instance, determinacy implies that $\omega_1\to(\omega_1)^{\omega_1}_2$. This is the *strong partition property*. A good deal of infinitary combinatorics under $\mathsf{AD}$ is about establishing such partition properties at various cardinals. The consistency strength of such an uncountable (well-orderable) cardinal is higher than for $\omega\to(\omega)^\omega_2$, as the assumption readily gives us that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are measurable cardinals which, in turn, gives us inner models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with two measurable cardinals (and more).

I suggest Jech's set theory book or Kanamori's **The higher infinite** to learn more about the subject. There is a very nice short book by Kleinberg devoted solely to consequences of these partition properties,

> [MR0479903 (58 #109)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=479903). Kleinberg, Eugene M. **[Infinitary combinatorics and the axiom of determinateness](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540084402)**. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 612. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1977. iii+150 pp. ISBN: 3-540-08440-1.